# Legend for summary statistics in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is the code for the plot

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(gp = factor(rep(letters[1:3], each = 10)), y = rnorm(30))
library(plyr)
ds <- ddply(df, .(gp), summarise, mean = mean(y), sd = sd(y))
ggplot(df, aes(x = gp, y = y)) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_point(data = ds, aes(y = mean), colour = 'red', size = 3)
```

[image]

I want to have a legend for this plot that will identify the data values and mean values some thing like this

```
Black point = Data
Red point   = Mean.
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: +1 for good question, reproducible example, visualization and well described desired output. The title could also include word "custom". I would imagine myself searching for a "custom legend in ggplot".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a manual scale, i.e. in your case `scale_colour_manual`. Then map the colours to values in the scale using the `aes()` function of each geom:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = gp, y = y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour="data")) +
  geom_point(data = ds, aes(y = mean, colour = "mean"), size = 3) +
  scale_colour_manual("Legend", values=c("mean"="red", "data"="black"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can combine the mean variable and data in the same data.frame and colour /size by column which is a factor, either `data` or `mean`

```
library(reshape2)

# in long format
dsl <- melt(ds, value.name = 'y')
# add variable column to df data.frame
df[['variable']] <- 'data'
# combine
all_data <- rbind(df,dsl)

# drop  sd rows

data_w_mean <- subset(all_data,variable != 'sd',drop = T)

# create vectors for use with scale_..._manual
colour_scales <- setNames(c('black','red'),c('data','mean'))
size_scales <- setNames(c(1,3),c('data','mean') )

ggplot(data_w_mean, aes(x = gp, y = y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = variable, size = variable)) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'Type', values = colour_scales) +
  scale_size_manual(name = 'Type', values = size_scales)
```

[image]

Or you could not combine, but include the column in both data sets

```
dsl_mean <- subset(dsl,variable != 'sd',drop = T)  
ggplot(df, aes(x = gp, y = y, colour = variable, size = variable)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = dsl_mean) +
  scale_colour_manual(name = 'Type', values = colour_scales) +
  scale_size_manual(name = 'Type', values = size_scales)
```

Which gives the same results